# ERROR in Could not resolve "./homemodule/home.module" from "/control-panel/src/app/core/core.module.ts"

Tags: angular

I have added global components and services in a module called core module and imported that module in app.module. The problem is when the app is started with ng serve command, It produces an error 
 **ERROR in Could not resolve "./homemodule/home.module" from "/control-panel/src/app/core/core.module.ts"**.

This error immediately disappears when i press cntrl + s(to save) . so every time when i start the app i have to simply save the code that the compiles again successfully.
Has someone experienced the same problem and resolved it???

Comment: Probably a mismatch in versions of `@angular/cli` and other `@angular/*` packages, assuming your paths are correct.

Comment: The home module is lazy loaded and did not give the full path. It works fine now. Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer myself. The reason is that I haven't added the full path. I added /control-panel/src/app/homemodule/home.module so it could then find the path and  it compiled successfully.